# How to select first row in group using expressions

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, linq-expressions

I have a task when the same table is used to work with different data which similar content. I use dynamic linq expressions to get data from sql.
The most complicated task for me was to choose distinct rows based on one field. The one of the tables is Parts, and I will show it as the sample.

I need to select the first part from db with each Description.
Sql request is:

```
SELECT * FROM [Parts] WHERE [Id] IN (SELECT MIN([Id]) FROM[Parts] GROUP BY [Description])
```

LINQ request is:

```
queryable = queryable.GroupBy(r => r.Dewcription).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

I should rewrite LINQ query to expressions. I have successed with GROUP BY:
var grouped = queryable.GroupBy(SelectedField, type); // using

```
public static IQueryable GroupBy([NotNull] this IQueryable source, string Property, [NotNull] Type type)
    {
        PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(Property);
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "r");
        MemberExpression member = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(member, parameter);
        MethodCallExpression resultExpression = GroupByCall(source, lambda, property.PropertyType, type);
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(resultExpression);
    }
```

// to apply Group by method

```
public static MethodCallExpression GroupByCall([NotNull] IQueryable queryable, LambdaExpression predicate, Type typeKey, Type typeSource)
    {
        MethodInfo MethodGroupBy = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
            .First(m => m.Name.Equals("GroupBy", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && m.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(typeSource, typeKey);
        Type QueryableType = typeSource.QueryableType();
        return Expression.Call(null, MethodGroupBy, Expression.Convert(queryable.Expression, QueryableType), Expression.Quote(predicate));
    }
```

// to get type of Queryable to convert from Queryable

```
public static Type QueryableType(this Type type)
    {
        var list = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type));
        MethodInfo Method = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod(nameof(Queryable.AsQueryable), new[] { typeof(IEnumerable) });
        var listAsQueryable = Method.Invoke(null, new[] { list });
        return listAsQueryable.GetType();
    }
```

The next step is to make expression for .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()). It is not possible to apply it directly, because the type of grouped entity is not known, and the result of grouping is IGrouping<string, object>, where object in fact is the type which we know on execution.
I need something like it:

```
var grouped = queryable.GroupBy(SelectedField, type).SelectGroupFirst(type); 

public static IQueryable SelectGroupFirst([NotNull] this IQueryable source, [NotNull] Type type)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "r");
    MemberExpression member = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, ...get enumerable...);
    ...apply First() or FirstOrDefault()...
    LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(member, parameter);
    MethodCallExpression resultExpression = SelectCall(source, lambda, ...IGrouping<string, type>..., type);
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery(resultExpression);
}

public static MethodCallExpression SelectCall(IQueryable queryable, LambdaExpression predicate, Type typeKey, Type typeSource)
{
    if (queryable == null) return null;
    var methods = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(m => m.Name.Equals("Select", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)); 
    MethodInfo MethodSelect = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .First(m => m.Name.Equals("Select", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && m.GetParameters().Length == 2).MakeGenericMethod(typeSource, typeKey);
    return Expression.Call(null, MethodSelect, queryable.Expression, Expression.Quote(predicate));
}
```

I have not found the way to make type definition of IGrouping<string, type> dynamically, to define the group enumeration property and to get access to it.

Alternative could be the way to mix usage of SQL and LINQ. Is there the way to use the above mentioned sql request for first selection of rows, and to modify it with LINQ for paging and filtering? I have not found any.

Comment: As I know, even you will run it not dynamically EF Core will not run this query,

Comment: As @Svyatoslav says, be aware that EF core has very limited support for `GroupBy`. Basically it doesn't support query shapes that do more than SQL's GROUPBY statement.

Comment: (`different data which similar content` looks broken.)